# Enforce altering string adheres to Typescript type union

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types

I have a library that requires a type like:

```
type Strings = "A" | "B"
```

Sometimes I will get a simple string like "A" or "B", other times I get something like "summedA" or "summedB". If alter the string, how can I convince typescript that I will make sure I format it correctly? For example:

```
functionThatRequiresType(input: Strings) {...}

const string: string = "summedA"

const newString = string.replace("summed", "")

functionThatRequiresType(newString) => calling throws error
```

Comment: `functionThatRequiresType(newString as 'A')` or `const newString = string.replace("summed", "") as 'A'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell TypeScript that `string.replace("summed", "")` returns a value of type `Strings` using `as`.

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=36#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwM5QLxQEQEFcoAfPAIVwFgAoGgMwFdkBjYRAe2SkZbc4BUAFgENgAJQgBHBongR0-cBAAUKMA2AAuWAhQYAlFADeAXxo1mndMCjWkabXb3Y86BgFt3EACaFz1S2RrKGQIAHc4e1QXJzQAOjkwABthZhVcN08fXAAaPFxDYUxIvXR-HlYOZCFRCWlZeUVIZVCI3TR9IA):

```
type Strings = "A" | "B"

function functionThatRequiresType(input: Strings) {}

const string: string = "summedA"

const newString = string.replace("summed", "") as Strings

functionThatRequiresType(newString)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use type casting:

```
const newString = string.replace("summed", "") as Strings
```

However, doing this might weaken the type system as TypeScript will believe that your type casting is right most of the time.

Thus, you have to use type casting cautiously.